# Making plots with world coordinates (WCSAxes)

Tags: python

I am on `astropy 3.0.2`, `python 3.6.5` and `matplotlib 2.2.2.`

I tried to follow the simple instruction explained here:
http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from astropy.wcs 
import WCS from astropy.io 
import fits from astropy.utils.data 
import get_pkg_data_filename 

filename = get_pkg_data_filename('galactic_center/gc_msx_e.fits') 
hdu = fits.open(filename)[0] 
wcs = WCS(hdu.header) 
plt.subplot(projection=wcs) 
plt.imshow(hdu.data, vmin=-2.e-5, vmax=2.e-4, origin='lower')
plt.grid(color='white', ls='solid') plt.xlabel('Galactic Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Galactic Latitude')
```

but, I encountered this kind of error:

> File "C:\Users\DavideAngelini\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2279, in get_tightbbox
>       bb.append(ax.get_tightbbox(renderer, bbox_extra_artists))
>
> TypeError: get_tightbbox() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the code that is causing this?

Comment: This is the code: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename

filename = get_pkg_data_filename('galactic_center/gc_msx_e.fits')

hdu = fits.open(filename)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, vmin=-2.e-5, vmax=2.e-4, origin='lower')
plt.grid(color='white', ls='solid')
plt.xlabel('Galactic Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Galactic Latitude')` You can also find it in the website i linked @kenlukas